# Regex matching emails containing * and [.]

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex for matching `*@xxx[.]gr` in js.

My regex so far :

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

I want : *@xxx.gr

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: @Toto I have edited my question

Comment: @TheNone How about this `.*@\w{3}.\w+`

Comment: What characters are allowed before (*) and after (xxx) @? [.] is literally [.] or any character in square brackets?

Comment: @AlexG all characters are allowed. Only "." is in square

Comment: So if I understand correctly, before @ any character (except I assume the ones you have in the negated set), after @ 3 characters followed by a dot in square and finally two characters?

Comment: @AlexG yes thats true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your specs correctly this should suit you:

```
/^[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+@[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]{3}\[\.\][^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]{2}$/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kfjAG9/2